# Check whether a given value is in a nested dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have this structure, converted using `json.load(json)`

```
jsonData = [ { 
thing: [
    name: 'a name',
    keys: [
        key1: 23123,
        key2: 83422
    ]
thing: [
    name: 'another name',
    keys: [
        key1: 67564,
        key2: 93453
    ]
etc....
} ]
```

I have `key1check = 67564`, 
I want to check if a thing's key1 matches this value

```
if key1check in val['thing']['keys']['key1'] for val in jsonData:
    print ('key found, has name of: {}'.format(jsonData['thing']['name'])
```

Should this work?  Is there a better was to do this?

Comment: I'm guessing your structure is supposed to be a dictionary inside of a dictionary inside of a dictionary (dictinception). Such as 'key#' is a dictionary to the key 'keys' and that is part of a dictionary inside of key 'thing' which includes also keys 'name' and 'thing'. If this is the case you need to look at the python syntax for this which is { } is the start and end of a dictionary. You may reference the keys using [ ] but you don't declare them that way.

Answer (score 2):

Not quite:

1. **in** is for inclusion in a sequence, such as a string or a list.  You're comparing integer values, so a simple **==** is what you need.
2. Your given structure isn't legal Python: you have brackets in several places where you're intending a dictionary; you need braces instead.

Otherwise, you're doing fine ... but you should *not* ask us if it will work: ask the Python interpreter by running the code.

Try this for your structure:

```
jsonData = [ 
{ "thing": {
    "name": 'a name',
    "keys": {
        "key1": 23123,
        "key2": 83422
    } } },
{ "thing": {
    "name": 'another name',
    "keys": {
        "key1": 67564,
        "key2": 93453
    } } }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through @Prune 's dictionary using something like this as long as the structure is consistent.

```
for item in jsonData:
    if item['thing']['keys']['key1'] == key1check:
        print("true")
    else:
        print("false")
```